# Couchbase Community 6.0 setup with 3 nodes

Tags: couchbase

If I'm running Couchbase Community Edition with 3 nodes on separate EC2 instances, what services should be running on each node?  The setup instructions had me put all services on the first instance and then just the data service on the 2nd instance.  My question is if I need to scale the database and I add more nodes, do all the queries run through the first node, or can you run the query service on multiple nodes and use all of the servers when you connect from your application.

Answer (score 0):

For Community Edition, any service you want to use *must* be on every node. I don't see how you could have added just the data service on the second node (unless you're actually using Enterprise edition).

But to answer your question, yes you can run the query service on multiple nodes. With Enterprise, you can use [multi-dimensional scaling](https://www.couchbase.com/multi-dimensional-scalability-overview) to allocate more resources to nodes that are just running query (for instance).

[image]

E.g. your data nodes get bigger hard drives, your query nodes get more RAM/CPUs.